# Phrase request: emphasizing benefits of performing an activity that is often perceived as boring

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I'm trying to convince readers that performing a particular activity *-that is often perceived as boring-* might be the best thing they can do for their business.

For instance:

> "The act of clarifying your vision statement might not be the first thing you want to clear your schedule for, but it might be the best thing you can spend your time on today."

Do you know any phrases or expressions I can use to make this sentence more elegant and/or powerful?

Comment: +1 Good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the word [**chore**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chore).

It perfectly conveys the sense of necessity over enjoyment.

> Checking your statement for errors may not be the most enticing chore, but it pays off dividends later.

Comment: This one is just absolutely brilliant! By adding the word *dividends* I'm confident it will appeal to the entrepreneurial audience.

Thank you @David M!

Answer (score 1):

‘Necessary evil’

Something that is repugnant, yet worth doing as it brings valuable benefits.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+necessary+evil

Answer (score 0):

It's an **important tedium**.

*As in*:
"Checking punctuation in your writing is an **important tedium**. It can be a really boring job to do, but it is worth all that and more."

Alastair Stewart, *[Kids Company trustees …](https://www.itv.com/news/2015-08-05/kids-company-trustees-and-charity-commission-should-remember-it-takes-two-to-tango/)* , "itv - news," 2015:

> What do Coldplay, J.K. Rowling and Damien Hirst know of management systems and double-entry bookkeeping? They employ accountants, managers and lawyers to look after all that **important tedium** whilst they sing, write and paint.

Comment: Thank you @Kris, I also really like the *'worth all that and more'* addition!

Comment: Tedium as a count noun??

Comment: @AntonSherwood Agreed. Note I did not imply that either!